# Loading data from database using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

I've a two dropdown lists for countries and cities.
The city dropdown data changes according to the city dropdown using ajax call.
Every thing works fine except for two countries when trying load thir cities I get server error 500 without any messages.
This is the controller function I use in the ajax call.
The country code is received correctly but it gives 500 server error with two countries France with country code "FR" and Germany with country code "DE"
I'm using laravel 5.4

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\LkpCity;

class CommonController extends Controller {

    public function getCities() {
        $country_code = request('country_code');
        $cities = LkpCity::where('CountryCode', '=',$country_code)->get();
        return response()->json(['cities' => $cities]);
    }

}
```

I've tried debugging the quire using laravel method toSql() but everything looks normal.The issue is not producible on the local machine it's only on the server.
so any help here? why only these two country codes gives an error

Comment: Change the local project db connection to connect it to the server db and then re-generate the issue on local and rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that the error is only on the server.
Are you sure there is a DB record for those 2 country's?

If so. try to dump the query on your server and add it too your question. Same with the query on your local machine

Comment: I ran the query on the server's database
SELECT * from city where CountryCode = "FR"
 and it returned the data correctly

Comment: Try what mayank is saying. connect your local db to your server db.